# Change the font of table using kable and/or kableExtra for pdf export from shiny

Tags: fonts, kable, kableextra

I have created a shiny app where the user can download a formatted version of a table as a pdf.  I have been able to style the table for my needs using kable and kable_extra, but I have not been able to change the font.

See the reproducible example below.  I have tried defining the font using the `html_font` parameter in `kable_styling`, and using the `latex_header_includes` parameter in `save_kable`. The code below shows my latest formatting attempts with both, but I have tried many others.

Can anyone advise how I can change the font?

```
df <- data.frame(animal = c("cat", "dog", "horse", "lemur"), lifespan = c(15, 12, 25, 37))

x <- kable(df, "latex", booktabs = T, linesep = c("", "", "", "\\hline"), col.names = NULL)  %>%
  add_header_above(c("Animal Lifespans" =2), line = F) %>%
  kable_styling(font_size = 5, full_width = TRUE, html_font = '"Arial Narrow"')

save_kable(x, "~/Downloads/test.pdf")

# I tried adding the font by adding the code below as a parameter to the save_kable function, but get errors 
# latex_header_includes = `c("\\\\usepackage{helvet}", "\\\\renewcommand{\\\\familydefault}{\sfdefault}")`
```

Comment: I don't know how to make it in Shiny, but be aware how to change font of kableextra's table in RMarkdown, do you need it? Maybe it will be useful for you?

Comment: Thanks manro.  I do know how to change the font in an RMarkdown document.  I am hoping to learn how to change the font if you are saving as pdf without an R Markdown.  My latex_header_includes attempt that is commented out in my example is my attempt at using the RMarkdown terminology within kableExtra.

Comment: Sorry, that I can't help you. Maybe, you should ask there: https://shiny.rstudio.com/help/ ?